# Can I extend within a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, extend

I have data that looks like this:

```
[[1, 100313], [2, 100313], [1, 100314], [3, 100315]]
```

With everything in string format (otherwise I can't iterate)

I want to run a for loop that looks through these elements and extends with [0, 0, 1] if it sees the second item in the list as 100313.  So ultimately it would look like this:

```
[[1, 100313, 0, 0, 1], [2, 100313, 0, 0, 1], [1, 100314], [3, 100315]]
```

I've run a for loop that looks like this:

```
for x, y in list:
    if y == 100313:
        list.extend([0,0,1])
```

and it doesn't change the list at all.  Why is that?

Comment: You're looping through the outer list, it seems. That for loop destructures the inner list into x and y, iff the inner list has exactly two elements. But then when you try to extend, you call extend on the **outer** list. Try making the loop variable the whole inner list and checking for 100313 in that. Then call extend on the inner list.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `list comprehension` like this example:

```
a = [[1, 100313], [2, 100313], [1, 100314], [3, 100315]]

final = [k+[0,0,1] if k[1] == 100313 else k for k in a]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 100313, 0, 0, 1], [2, 100313, 0, 0, 1], [1, 100314], [3, 100315]]
```

Update:

You asked to add another `if ... else` block in one `list comprehension`. You can do it like this example:

```
a = [[1, 100313], [2, 100313], [1, 100314], [3, 100315]]
final = [k+[0,0,1] if k[1] == 100313 else k+[0,1,0] if k[1] == 100314 else k for k in a]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 100313, 0, 0, 1], [2, 100313, 0, 0, 1], [1, 100314, 0, 1, 0], [3, 100315]]
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I wanted to also extend a [0,1,0] if k[1] == 100314.  Can this all be in one list comprehension?

Comment: you could use if k[1] in {100313, 100314}

Comment: @iklinac but its a different extension...how do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by different extension

Comment: @ikliniac for k[1] ==100314 I want to add a [0,1,0], for k[1] == 100313 I want to add a [0,0,1]  In other words, I'm treating them differently

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with big amounts of data and want to avoid inefficient use of memory it's better to use a generator expression. They look pretty similar to list comprehension except for instead of square brackets they have parentheses:

```
from __future__ import print_function

a = [[1, 100313], [2, 100313], [1, 100314], [3, 100315]]
final = (k+[0,0,1] if k[1] == 100313 else k+[0,1,0] if k[1] == 100314 else k for k in a)

for i in final:
    print(i, end='')

print()
```

The generator expression returns a generator object instead of a whole list. You can lazily print the elements one by one by looping through the returned generator.

Note that this only makes sense if you have really big lists and not like in the example of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use list[x][y] instead of y in if statement. And use list[x] instead of list the next line. This will surely work.
Because what you are trying to do is you are trying to extend your list, but what you actually want is to extend the element of the list.hope it helps